# Plot a best fit over a scatter plot with holoviews

Tags: python, pandas, holoviews

I am trying to make a best fit line for all of my graphs in holoviews, right now it just makes a line based on all the data instead of each graph individually.

```
vdims = [('year avg', 'Yearly Average Temperature')]
ds = hv.Dataset(temp, ['Year','State Name'], vdims)
ds = ds.aggregate(function=np.mean)

scat = hv.Scatter(ds,'Year','year avg')
layout = ds.to(hv.Scatter,'Year','year avg') * hv.Slope.from_scatter(scat)
layout.opts(opts.Curve(width=800, height=400, framewise=True))
```

Which gives this

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.plotting.links import DataLink
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['Even'] = df['D']%2 == 0

vdims = [('A', 'A')]
ds = hv.Dataset(df, ['B','Even'], vdims)
#ds = ds.aggregate(function=np.mean) this does nothing here, in my code it takes the mean of 100 or so data points in each group for each year.

scat = hv.Scatter(ds,'B','A')
layout = ds.to(hv.Scatter,'B','A') * hv.Slope.from_scatter(scat)
layout.opts(opts.Curve(width=800, height=400, framewise=True))
```

The idea is to make a scatter plot grouped by a variable in the dataframe, in this case if D is even or odd, and also plot a best fit line of that same grouped scatter plot.

What I have is a set of grouped scatter plots but with a best fit line based on all of the data combined, not grouped by even and odd.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Do you want me to include my dataset?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Okay, I think I have something that shows that